# Make Project web app site a Template site in another Project server web app

Tags: 2013, workflow, powershell, site-template, project-server

I have one test WA on which I have Project web app.
Each project site has own SharePoint site where we created several custom lists/libraries and we created custom reports in dashboard designer (there is a workflow, that on creation of Project site creates a SharePoint site for that Project).

I want to make that Project site a template in another Project web application, with all workflows, reports and custom actions in lists/libraries we have now on test system.

Is this doable? If yes any help how to do it would be appreciated.

I know there is backup/restore or export/import, but not sure if those are the right path this time for me.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done.

IMPORTANT NOTE: Templates in SharePoint 2013 have changed.  For each new site created, you have to upload a template file "CompanyNameTemplate.wsp" that you created/bought.

1. Export your site as a template, in this specific case check the option to include content.
2. Create a new site, use the pick a custom site later.
3. After the site has been created, the will be a Gallery link on the template page and you will need to click on that and upload your *.wsp to the site and then go to the template custom tab and use the template that is now in the Gallery.